# Segfault Cannot access memory at address

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, controls

I got a segmentation fault on the code section below: (regarding this segfault , I am asking 2 question in one topic)

```
req_cw(ECM_REQUEST *er, int32_t flag, int32_t reader_types){

    LL_NODE *ptr;
    for (ptr = er->matching_rdr->initial ; ptr ; ptr = ptr->nxt) {
        if (ptr == er->fail)
            break;
    rdr = (struct s_reader*)ptr->obj;
    we_equest(rdr->fd, er);
    }
}
```

As you see, even with the control structure with `if(ptr->obj && ptr)` to be sure `ptr` (or `ptr->obj` won't be `null` pointer) but it doesn't prevent it and after segmentation fault when I tried to print the value `ptr->obj` with:

print ptr->obj  , gdb says :

> (gdb) print ptr $1 = (LL_NODE *) 0x149
>
> (gdb) x 0x149
>
> 0x149: Cannot access memory at address 0x149

My question is: How can I prevent this segmentation fault , why this segmentation fault happens and how would I fix it?

1. Regarding this segfault , when with gdb , i had checked frame 1 (one frame before when segfault happened) , i figured out that

er->cw is `"\000 <repeats 15 times>"`
my question is how could I control if `er->cw` won't be equal of `"'\000' <repeats 15 times"`?

I did this, I know it's not correct (and I missed something) , that's why I ask here

```
if (er->cw)
req_cw(er , ...)
```

The problem is  with adding `if(er->cw)`. I think `cw` is character and I shouldn't behave like integer , but I don't know how to check it to not be zero?, I mean , even with this line again when I check with gdb , still `er->cw` with value of "'\000' " is passing , so how with if control block I could check when `er->cw` is not equal to '\000' " ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `0x149` is definitely an invalid pointer... the problem is in another part of the code you haven't showed us

Comment: @Karoly , how with gdb i could figure out ox149 why is invalid , i mean how with gdb i could check that invalid pointer u mentioned?     btw , my second part question is about how to check if cw is not equal to "'\000' repeating 15 times" with if funtion ?            btw , since u said the problem is in another part of the code , what part u meant? (if u said the function name , i will provide that source code too . Thanks

Comment: @All at least my second part question muse be simple to many people of this forum! isn't , so after 50 review still , no respond to second part , so if i check with if(strlen(er->cw) != 0) is this control to er->cw valid for prevent the value be '\000 repeat 15 times ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`As you see, even with the control structure with if(ptr->obj || ptr) to be sure ptr (or ptr->null won't be null pointer)`

No... that actually doesn't ensure that neither will be NULL, that sets you up for a seg fault. The `||` will evaluate ***both*** sides before it quits, and you set up the logic backwards anyway. You wanted `&&` and you need to flip them or it will deference what could be a `NULL` pointer:

```
if(ptr && ptr->obj)
```

---

> > after segmentation fault when I tried to print the value ptr->obj with:
> >       
> > print ptr->obj , gdb says :
> >     
> > ...
> >     
> >     0x149: Cannot access memory at address 0x149

I've never seen an address of `0x149` be valid, what hardware platform are you on?

---

> er->cw is "\000 " my question is how could I control if er->cw won't be equal of "'\000'

This is not clear, could you show the structure for `er`? Are you saying that `er->cw` is a `char *` type and is set to `"\000 <repeats 15 times>"`?

Comment: Thanks for replying , cw is  uchar cw[16]; (unsigned char)
Hardware is SH4 / stlinux

Comment: regard if(ptr && ptr->obj) i knew , i said this is a typo caused by editing of moderator!

Comment: @nimatajfar yes, and you also said (in the other comment) that you tried `(!ptr && !ptr->obj)` which is incorrect. I see in or edit that you meant it without the `!`s.  The SH4 is 32-bit hardware, so why aren't you trying to access the address with a 32-bit address? C isn't going to know which way to pad that if that was your intention. Since `cw` is an array of characters then you need to compare char by char or with a str function, the initial `\000` is an escape char and you should see that `cw[0] == 0`

Answer (score 1):

> As you see, even with the control structure with if(ptr->obj || ptr) to be sure ptr (or ptr->null won't be null pointer)

The problem is the order you are doing the tests, when compiled the `ptr->obj` is done first, so if `ptr` is null you are accessing invalid memory get get the `obj` member.
Reverse the order of the tests `if (ptr  || ptr->obj)`

**BUT** that will still not be right... Your `OR` logic is wrong too, the code should be...

```
if ((ptr != NULL) && (ptr->obj != NULL))
{
   // use the pointer
}
```

Comment: hmm , no this is not the case , after editing by moderators this happens (u had find a typo in first post),  in the code i had checked with if (!ptr && !ptr->obj) which is definetly same on what u said , hmm , ok , i limit my question to one part , if i want to check er->cw which is char of array (longth of array is 15) the elements won't be zero , how could i do it? does strlen (er->cw) != '\000' do the job or not?

Comment: It depends what er->cw is used for... if it is a text-string then checking `if (er->cw[0] == '\0') empty_string` is enough to test for an empty string.
Testing for `if (er->cw=="\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0")` is BAD idea.

Comment: Thanks Anonymouse , is there any difference between checking if (er->cw[0] == '\0' or '\000'?

Comment: The absolute purists will say yes there is a difference, \0 is the NULL terminator character, where as \000 is ascii character 0. 

But in reality they are the same.