# deleting values less than a given value in a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm writing a code that simulates a music playlist. One of my functions should delete all the songs that are before a given year. But I'm having some issues getting my code to work. The function wont delete the nodes, when I use a function to print the list after running this function, it's completely unchanged. Can anyone help?

function

```
void deleteLessThanYear(int y)
{
     Node* current = head; //position current at head

      if( head == NULL)
      { cout << "No nodes in list" << endl << endl;}

      while(current->getYear() > y)
      {
        current = current->getNext();
        if (current->getYear() <= y)
        { 
          Node* currentPrev = current->getPrev();
          Node* currentNext = current->getNext();

          currentPrev->setNext(currentNext);
          currentNext->setPrev(currentPrev);
          delete current; 
        }
      }
```

.main function call

```
cout << endl;
cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
cout << "DELETE LESS THAN YEAR" << endl;
playlist->deleteLessThanYear(2005);
playlist->printList();
```

Comment: This looks like the sort of thing best addressed by stepping through the code in a debugger to see when the flow of execution no longer matches the expected flow. (Keep the list short for debugging.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not traversing the list correctly when looking for nodes to remove. If the list is empty, the code will crash. If the loop encounters a node that is not older than the specified year, the loop ends prematurely.  When removing a node, the code does not correctly account for the possibility of that node being at the front or back of the list.

Try this instead:

```cpp
void deleteLessThanYear(int y)
{
    Node* current = head; //position current at head

    if (!head)
    {
        cout << "No nodes in list" << endl << endl;
        return;
    }

    do
    {
        Node* currentNext = current->getNext();
        if (current->getYear() < y)
        {
            Node* currentPrev = current->getPrev();
            if (currentPrev) currentPrev->setNext(currentNext);
            if (currentNext) currentNext->setPrev(currentPrev);
            if (current == head) head = currentNext;
            delete current;
        }
        current = currentNext;
    }
    while (current);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have several errors in your implementation:

1. no `return;` statement within the `if( head == NULL)` condition. if you don't return after you hit this condition, you would end up running `current->getYear()`, resulting in [Segmentation Fault cannot access memory at address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203184/segfault-cannot-access-memory-at-address)
2. Not checking `current != NULL` condition inside the `while(current->getYear() > y)` condition. If all the values of list are greater than `y`, you end up traversing the whole list, thus reaching the end i.e, `NULL` pointer which will again result in `Segmentation Fault`.
3. What if `head` has year value <= `y`, you have not handled this case.
4. You stop at first node having the year > `y`, thus deleting only the next node but you mentioned to delete "all" the songs. You need to traverse the complete list and delete all those nodes having year values <= `y`.

The complete implementation needs to be changed as follows:

```
void deleteLessThanYear(int y)
{
    // Handling the case if head has year > y
    while(head != NULL && head->getYear() > y){
        head = head->getNext();
    }

    if( head == NULL)
    {
        cout << "No nodes in list" << endl << endl;
        return; // return
    }else{
        head->setPrev(NULL);
    }

    Node* current = head; //position current at modified head

    while(current != NULL){
        if(current->getYear() <= y){
            Node* currentPrev = current->getPrev();
            Node* currentNext = current->getNext();
            currentPrev->setNext(currentNext);
            // You need to check here if currentNext exists or not
            if(currentNext != NULL){
                currentNext->setPrev(currentPrev);
            }
            current = currentPrev;
        }
        current = current->getNext();
    }
}
```